# Condtion between two json properties java

Tags: java, testng

I want in object to make condition for example if in response we have stateCode, choose property stateCode, if we have stateName in response choose stateName, it that possible, do you have solution?

This is example of object:

```
public class AdminAddressModel implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("secondary")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = true)
    @Expose
    private String secondary;

    @SerializedName("zipCode")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String zipCode;

    @SerializedName("city")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String city;

    @SerializedName("stateName")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String stateName;

    @SerializedName("state")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String state;

    @SerializedName("primary")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String primary;

    public void setSecondary(String secondary){
        this.secondary = secondary;
    }

    public String getSecondary(){
        return secondary;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode){
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getZipCode(){
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName){
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public String getStateName(){
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setState(String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

    public void setPrimary(String primary){
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public String getPrimary(){
        return primary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return
                "ShippingAddress{" +
                        "secondary = '" + secondary + '\'' +
                        ",zipCode = '" + zipCode + '\'' +
                        ",city = '" + city + '\'' +
                        ",stateName = '" + stateName + '\'' +
                        ",state = '" + state + '\'' +
                        ",primary = '" + primary + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
}
```

This is stateCode that I want to include there and to make condition if in response that I verify we have stateCode, choose state code, if we have stateName, choose stateName, someone help?

```
    @SerializedName("stateCode")
    @ResponseRequiredField(canBeEmpty = false)
    @Expose
    private String stateCode;

public void setStateCode(String stateCode){
    this.stateCode= stateCode;
}

public String getStateCode(){
    return stateCode;
}
```

Also I'm using common assert function to verify object model and response that I get

AdminAddressModel does not contain property stateCode,
Required field stateName missing in response

response that I get, that's why I want that condition, in EPs that have in response stateCOde choose stateCode property to verify, if they have stateName than choose stateName

Comment: Which part is supposed to do any choosing here? And is the result of the choice supposed to be saved somewhere?

Comment: When I run a test, I'm using assert to assert object and what I get from response

Comment: and what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm using for example same model for different tests and in some test I have response stateCode and in some stateName, so I want to make condition, if in response is stateCode then choose stateCode

Comment: You're going to have to show your test code and clarify what exactly is your issue in the post.

Comment: Then simply call the getters and check if they return null.

Answer (score 1):

As the aim is creating a satisfactory condition you can cover the 4 possibilities:

```
public void checkForStateCodeOrName() {

            if (stateCode != null && stateName != null) {
                // There's both stateCode and stateName
                return;
            }

            if (stateCode != null || stateName != null) {
                // at least one has value
                if (stateCode == null) {
                    // You got a stateName!

                } else {
                    // You got a stateCode
                }
            } else {
                // both are empty!
            }}
```